# PHP Array sort up to set number then from 1

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with the following structure, and I want to sort it in an odd way.

```
Array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

I want to sort it based on a current value. If the current value is 7, I'd like to sort from 7 up to the highest number, and then from 1 back to the current value. So the array would look like follows:

```
Array(7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you post it in your question?

Comment: I've tried playing around with usort with no luck so far.

Comment: arrange it ascending first. then find the value inside the sorted array. start with that

Comment: Nice question, I've had a play with this in custom sorting functions and can't seem to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question itself seems naive (in the technical sense), meaning that I have a feeling some details have been omitted. But here is a way to do it given the simple instructions/example you've provided:

```
$arr = array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1);

sort($arr);

print_r(
    array_merge(
        array_slice($arr, array_search(7, $arr)),
        array_slice($arr, 0, array_search(7, $arr))
    )
);
```

http://codepad.org/kweQxjGE

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what I would do is sort and cut the array then merge on the rest. Like this:

```
function reorder($needle, $haystack) {
    sort($haystack);
    $final = array_merge(array_splice($haystack, array_search($needle, $haystack), (sizeof($haystack)-1)), $haystack);
    return $final;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(reorder(7, array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)));
```

This would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 5
    [9] => 6
)
```